# How to match particular word in the list to pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-re

```
a = ['bed', 'mattress', 'sheets', 'pillow', 'admission kits']

df = pd.DataFrame({'sr.no':[1,2,3,4,5], 'des': ['2 bed rooms', 'natural language processing', '2x2 sheets grabs', '2 meter long pillow', '2x30mm long']})

df =   sr.no       des
       1           2 bed rooms
       2           natural language processing
       3           2x2 sheets grabs
       4           2 meter long pillow
       5           2x30mm long
```

Here is list 'a' and dataframe 'df'. so here I want to match elements in list 'a' with dataframe column 'des'. if 'a' list of word present in 'des' column then print matched word otherwise print not match.

Here is the output that I want:

```
out=   sr.no    des                            output
       1        2 bed rooms                    bed
       2        natural language processing    not match
       3        2x2 sheets grabs               sheets 
       4        2 meter long pillow            pillow
       5        2x30mm long                    not match
```

How I can do this using python?

Comment: Can there be multiple matches?

Comment: Can you change your expected ouput? because accepted answer not match what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we only want to see if there is a match, we can use `str.contains` for the check and `np.where` to assign values:

```
df['output'] = np.where(df['des'].str.contains('|'.join(a)), 'match', 'not match')
```

Output:

```
   sr.no                          des     output
0      1                  2 bed rooms      match
1      2  natural language processing  not match
2      3             2x2 sheets grabs      match
3      4          2 meter long pillow      match
4      5                  2x30mm long  not match
```

Comment: Instead of printing matched word how I can print 'match' only

Comment: Solution failed with `'admission kits'`

Comment: @ShrikantShejwal_IND if you want to see the exact matches, use jezrael's solution. If you want to see if there is a match or not, my solution suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `split` solutions, because in list are joined values by `space` here `'admission kits'`, for avoid it use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
pat = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(x for x in a))
df['output'] = df['des'].str.extract(pat).fillna('not match')
print (df)
   sr.no                          des     output
0      1                  2 bed rooms        bed
1      2  natural language processing  not match
2      3             2x2 sheets grabs     sheets
3      4          2 meter long pillow     pillow
4      5                  2x30mm long  not match
```

Comment: `(x for x in a)` is an uninteresting way of saying `a`.